# LWC Is it possible to pass parameters to dynamic picklist datasource in property?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community-builder

Does anyone know if it is possible to pass parameters from the experience builder to an apex method used as a datasource in a LWC property?

```
<property
            name="itemID"
            type="String"
            datasource="apex://ApexPicklist"
            label="Items to display"
            description="The item to display"
/>
```

What I need access to is dynamically filter the items to show in the pick list

```
global override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
//get parameters values here...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want to send to Apex from Builder?

Comment: Don't think it's possible to add a parameter. This technique is to construct options in apex and pass to LWC as a property

Comment: I need to dynamically filter the items to show in the pick list

Comment: AFAIK, only properties we get from DesignTimePageContext are `entityName` and `pageType`. Maybe those could be useful for your usecase.